# ASP .Net - Entity Framework - MobileAppService - Error in pushing entity object to backend

Tags: entity-framework, azure, xamarin, code-first

I am using the offline sync feature in Xamarin to sync data between my mobile app and my MobileAppService hosted on Azure.
I used Entity Framework (V6.1.3), created my database using code-first migrations using visual studio package manager. Database is Microsoft SQL Server, hosted on Azure.
When I use offline sync, data is inserted into the database with no problem. But when I call the web api directly and send an object in JSON, the server throws an unknown exception when executing `InserAsync` (I connected a debugger to the MobileAppService running on Azure to figure out which command is causing problem):

> Exception thrown: 'System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException' in mscorlib.dll

The api endpoint code is simply as follows:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUser([FromBody] User item)
    {            
        User current = await InsertAsync(item);            
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id , CreatedAt = System.DateTime.Now }, current);
    }
```

And this is how I am calling the api in my Xamarin client:

```
var JsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                    
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("tables/User/PostUser", httpContent);
```

Shockingly, if I call the same api entry point using postman, everything works fine. I am confused and can't think of anything else as the source of this problem.

I caught the exception thrown by the web api and checked the values. Here is the screenshot of the watch window in remote debug mode:
[image: Watch view of remote debug]

The error might be related to the value of AzureVersion, but I don't have any idea how to fix it since the Version of the Request message is set to 1.1 (same when I call the api via postman).

Comment: Could you post some code?  What version of the entity framework are you using?  What type of database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem originated from using `AppServiceHelpers.Models.EntityData`, which is installed as a NuGet package. My entities all inherit from `EntityData` which adds some properties to the entity, one of which is `AzureVersion`:

```
public class EntityData
{        
    ...       
    [Version]
    public string AzureVersion { get; set; }
}
```

AzureVersion is marked with the attribute `[Version]` (`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Version`). However, `JsonConvert` does not realize this attribute and assigns the name `AzureVersion` to this property in the serialized object (instead of `Version`), which is not defined in the MobileServiceContext in the backend.

To solve the problem, I defined my own EntityData helper class, and explicitly assigned the property name to `Version`:

```
public class MyEntityData
{        
    [Version]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Version")]
    public string AzureVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Without this workaround, the context only works with OfflineSync; because, the `Version` attribute is realized by the `MobileServiceClient.SyncContext` and the object is stored in the local SQLStore with the property correctly set to `Version`, and then pushed to the backend following the `SyncContext.PushAsync()`. However, if you push the object directly to backend, the property holds the unidentified name of `AzureVersion`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I have checked the `InsertAsync` method from the `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.dll`, and I found that this error could be caused by several exceptions (e.g. [DbEntityValidationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationexception(v=vs.113).aspx), [DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception(v=vs.113).aspx), [DbUpdateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception(v=vs.113).aspx), etc.) when saving your data to database. In order to locate this issue, you need to catch the detailed error message, you could follow the approaches below:

- Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the detailed error from the response as follows:

[image]

- [Remote debug](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/) your web app, and you could wrap `InsertAsync` with `try-catch` for capturing the detailed error as follows:

[image]

In summary, you could try to locate the specific error and solve it. Or you could provide more detailed error about this issue for us to locate it.

Comment: version 1.1 is for HTTP. Based on your screenshot, I found a error about ModelState with `item.AzureVersion`, have you defined this property in your User entity? I peeked your back-end URL and I could directly invoke `tables/User/PostUser` with the user info `{id: "005012c8577c46beb3a9140000000000",password: "test",email:"test"}` successfully. I assumed that since the offline sync could work, the `JsonContent` you posted may invalid, please check it.